# Mysql database Error while updating a field

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

Iam using a Java Swing Application to Update a column in Mysql table. Here is My code(part)

```
String qunty = txtWithdraw.getText();
String partno = txtNo.getText();
int qty = Integer.parseInt(qunty);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, "username", "password");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sell = "update Store_info_table set qnty_received = qnty_received - " + qty +      "where Part_number = '" + partno + "'";
                st.executeUpdate(sell);
```

I am getting the Exception that:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Part_number = 'DF6534'' at line 1
```

I want to Update the qnty_received field so that it is equal to the Original value minus the value passed by the user i.e (int qty). What Error Am I making?

Comment: you can print out the `sell` and see the actual SQL that you are trying to run. easy to debug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a space before the where:

```
 " where Part_number = '" + partno + "'";
```

As a good practice, I recommend you to use `PreparedStatement` and set your parameters with the same. Concatenating the parameters dynamically may force the db engine to parse a new SQL statement every time.

> A SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a PreparedStatement
>   object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this
>   statement multiple times.

See: [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Oh I am surprised I did not see that. Thank you guys for the Insight. You are right. I must have missed that. I almost raked my Brains checking where the Error was.

Comment: Not sure how or where this code is used but as davidmontoyago suggests you should use PreparedStatemen. If this code gets `qty` or `partno` from a outside source such as a web form you are exposing yourself to a SQL injection attack. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection I just noticed its a Swing app. Still a vulnerability.

Answer (score 3):

Missing space:

```
... + qty +      "where ...
                  ^--- here
```

which makes your query something like

```
... qnty_received - blahwhere
```